# AlertDailog support x,y axis positioning but Dialog not in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to set position for my dialog. I'm using custom view so I go with `Dialog` class to create alert dialog. Here my problem is, x,y position does not work with `Dialog` alert but works with `AlertDialog` alert. I don't know why it happening. Thank in advance...

Code for alert dialog using `Dialog` class and this dialog dos not showing on given position,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    Log.v("ShelfShareFragment", "X-Axis: "+mXAxis+" Y-Axis: "+mYAxis);
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.anim.anim_fade_in);
    wmlp.x = mXAxis; // x position
    wmlp.y = mYAxis; // y position

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_shelf_share,
            null);

    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
            dialog.show()
```

Code for alert dialog using `AlertDialog` class. This one working fine, but I need to create my dialog using `Dialog` class.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_shelf_share,
            null);
    builder.setTitle("Checking");
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    Log.v("ShelfShareFragment", "X-Axis: "+mXAxis+" Y-Axis: "+mYAxis);
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = mXAxis; // x position
    wmlp.y = mYAxis; // y position
    dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.anim.anim_zoom_out);
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the code

```
getWindow().setAttributes()
```

please check